# Sort String column in PyQt:QTableWidget based on non-string Value

Tags: pyqt4, columnsorting

I am trying to sort numerals (float & int) which are formatted to add $ and comma etc. and converted to QString before being added to QTableWidgetItem. But sorting on these columns does not work because sorting is based on string data. Is there a way to display data as String but sort it based on underlying integer/float value. I am doing something as follows:

```
self.constituentsTableWidget.setSortingEnabled(False)
for i in xrange(p.getNumInstruments()):
   employee = p.getEmployee(i)

   item = QTableWidgetItem(QString(unicode('{}'.format(re.sub("(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))", r"\1,", "%.2f" % employee.WorkDays)))))
   self.constituentsTableWidget.setItem(i, cols['WorkDays'], item)

self.constituentsTableWidget.setSortingEnabled(True)
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks
Rahul

Answer (score 0):

I simply way to do that, inheritance `QtGui.QTableWidgetItem` and create your own. Next, override method [bool QTableWidgetItem.**lt** (self, QTableWidgetItem other)](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qtablewidgetitem.html#__lt__) to compare your own case;

**Example**

```
import re
import sys
import random
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class QCustomTableWidgetItem (QtGui.QTableWidgetItem):
    def __init__ (self, value):
        super(QCustomTableWidgetItem, self).__init__(QtCore.QString('%.2f $' % value))

    def __lt__ (self, other):
        if (isinstance(other, QCustomTableWidgetItem)):
            selfDataValue  = float(re.sub(r'[ $]', '', str(self.data(QtCore.Qt.EditRole).toString())))
            otherDataValue = float(re.sub(r'[ $]', '', str(other.data(QtCore.Qt.EditRole).toString())))
            return selfDataValue < otherDataValue
        else:
            return QtGui.QTableWidgetItem.__lt__(self, other)

class QCustomTableWidget (QtGui.QTableWidget):
    def __init__ (self, parent = None):
        super(QCustomTableWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setColumnCount(2)
        self.setRowCount(5)
        for row in range(self.rowCount()):
            self.setItem(row, 0, QCustomTableWidgetItem(random.random() * 1e4))
            self.setItem(row, 1, QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(QtCore.QString(65 + row)))
        self.setSortingEnabled(True)

myQApplication = QtGui.QApplication([])
myQCustomTableWidget = QCustomTableWidget()
myQCustomTableWidget.show()
sys.exit(myQApplication.exec_())
```

Hope is helps;

Comment: Thanks mate. I ended up implementing the same. I am new to python and QT framework; was wondering if there is an obvious way of setting sort field for any qtablewidgetitem.

Comment: On the other hand, Your can create your own filter by 'QSortFilterProxyModel'. But, Isn't correct your answer directly. YOur can find information this method in qt official web site.